# Angular 4 Component Bind Function

Tags: angular

I'm making a custom component to build a table.

```
export class TableComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() records: any[];
    @Input() caption: string;
    @Input() config: TableConfig[];
}

export class TableConfig {
    basePath: string;
    actions?: object[];
}

//Actions example
/*

action = { icon: "", description: "", onClick: thisMustReceiveAFunction }

*/
```

I just call my component where I want the table

```
<my-table
     [records]="entities"
     [caption]="Table"
     [config]="myConfig">
</my-table>
```

And initialize my config inside my component caller

```
myConfig: TableConfig = {
    basePath: "users",
    actions: [
        {
            icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil",
            description: "edit",
            onClick: this.MyEditFunction
        },
        {
            icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash",
            description: "delete"
            onClick: this.MyDeleteFunction
        }
    ]
};

MyEditFunction(): void { console.log('edit clicked'); }
MyDeleteFunction(): void { console.log('delete clicked'); }
```

But when I try to make a call at my table template, it doesnt work.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let action of config.actions" (click)="action.onClick()">
    <span class="{{action.icon}}"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: you get any error?? if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using type safety operator **`?`** because the DOM renders even before your data is retrieved.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let action of config?.actions" 
     (click)="action.onClick()">
    <span class="{{action?.icon}}"></span>
</button>
```

or you can use an `*ngIf` to ensure that the DOM is not loaded if the data is not available as below,

```
<span *ngIf="config.actions.length >  0">
   <button class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let action of config.actions" (click)="action.onClick()">
        <span class="{{action.icon}}"></span>
   </button>
 </span>
```

Comment: I think that its not the problem but now I rewrite the code and its working...So I will accept your answer because of the ? trick :D